# Reverse concat in Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir, standard-library

Is there a standard library function in Elixir (or Erlang) to concatenate the reverse of a list in front of some other list? Basically I'm looking for an equivalent of `reverse_:::` in Scala.

The rationale is that it's handy when implementing a tail-recursive algorithm on a list. During recursion, you hold on to some of the elements for later by adding them onto the front of an accumulator list. In the end you can reverse-concat them onto the remainder of the assembled list in one go (which should be pretty efficient).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a reverse and concat in Erlang by using [`lists:reverse/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#reverse-2).

I think the documentation explanation and example are clear enough:

> `reverse(List1, Tail) -> List2`.
>
> Returns a list with the elements in `List1` in reverse order, with the
>   tail `Tail` appended.

```
> lists:reverse([1, 2, 3, 4], [a, b, c]).
[4,3,2,1,a,b,c]
```

Comment: We also have [`Enum.reverse/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#reverse/2) in Elixir.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. I did not see the 2-argument version earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The function to reverse a list in Elixir is [`Enum.reverse/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reverse/1), and [`Enum.reverse/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reverse/2) can be used to reverse and concatenate:

```elixir
iex> Enum.reverse([1,2,3])
[3, 2, 1]
iex> Enum.reverse([1,2,3], [:a, :b, :c])
[3, 2, 1, :a, :b, :c]
```