# Erlang BIFs inside lists module

Tags: erlang

Inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777787/reverse-concat-in-elixir) question, I was curious to see how `lists:reverse/2` is implemented in the source code inside `lists.erl` module.
I found out that there is no implementation for `lists:reverse/2` inside `lists.erl`, but there is an implementation for `lists:reverse/1` that uses `lists:reverse/2`:

```
reverse([] = L) ->
    L;
reverse([_] = L) ->
    L;
reverse([A, B]) ->
    [B, A];
reverse([A, B | L]) ->
    lists:reverse(L, [B, A]).
```

At the top of the file there are some lines that tells that `lists:reverse/2` (and some other functions) are BIFs:

```
%%% BIFs
-export([keyfind/3, keymember/3, keysearch/3, member/2, reverse/2]).

...

%% Shadowed by erl_bif_types: lists:reverse/2
-spec reverse(List1, Tail) -> List2 when
      List1 :: [T],
      Tail :: term(),
      List2 :: [T],
      T :: term().

reverse(_, _) ->
    erlang:nif_error(undef).
```

**Question:** First, I couldn't find the actual implementations of those BIFs. Where can I find them? Second, If someone also knows to explain why is it organized that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lists` BIFs are implemented in [`erts/emulator/beam/erl_bif_lists.c`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/erts/emulator/beam/erl_bif_lists.c). Parts of heavily-used standard modules such as `lists` are implemented as BIFs for efficiency and performance.